# XRDP To connect to Raspbian - Master session

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, vnc, xrdp

This question actually exists in different formats, and a lot have the same person, giving the same answer - However it isn't quite hitting what I need.

I would like to be able to connect to my Rasp Pi, and see the physical-session that is on the box. I have installed `tightvnc` and `xrdp`.

Using an empty port (with `ask-1`) I can connect to my own session. Using a base `-1` I can, again, connect. However, while I can browse folders, and use the terminal - If I open an app, such as Chromium - It doesn't open for me. However, it DOES open on the connection that is directly in there.

I would appreciate any advice.

My end goal is to be able to RDP into it, and see the open windows/files/folders/compilations it has going, just as I was connecting to another system.

I've tried matching the 'default port', the `ask-1` to be whatever it's currently on, but I'm unsure how to find that out.

**Update**

It appears that it may be a Chromium specific bug(And other apps.) Judging by [Chromium Support Forums](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=43383) - Has anyone found a work-around, in this case?

Answer (score 0):

This is tied to the bug in Chromium in which it can't be opened for more than one session at a time. You can use `--user-dir` flag to make different versions open, but the solution for me ended up to 
`pkill chrome`
or
`pkill chromium` respectively
On whichever session I needed it on.